# Is it possible to update interactive_output manually?

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

I want to ask is it possible to update the output manually while using interactive_output?
the function I'm currently using is pretty complicated, so the output kind of lags a bit when the slider widget is used.

much thanks!

Comment: Have you tried altering the `continuous_update` parameter of the widget? This will mean the function only runs when the widget stops moving, rather than all the intervals inbetween. https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Disabling-continuous-updates